# I cannot get GPS coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, gps, location

My problem is that I cannot get GPS coordinates by using LocationManager class and LocationListener.  This is the code I call in OnCreate():

```
    locMgr = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    currentLocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, currentLocListener);
    locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, currentLocListener);
```

And I have a class MyLocationListener that implements class LocationListener

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String coordinates[] = {""+location.getLatitude(),""+location.getLongitude()};
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
    GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1E6), (int)(lng*1E6));
    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(19);

    MyMapOverlays marker = new MyMapOverlays(p);
    List<Overlay> listofOverLays = mapview.getOverlays();
    listofOverLays.clear();
    listofOverLays.add(marker);
    mapview.invalidate();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS is disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS is Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}}
```

I can get the location by mocking location in Emulator Control in DDMS. So I try to test on my real phone. when I install it on my phone, it can't get the current location automatically although I turned on GPS and wifi.

I try to run another google map app from market on to my real phone, it worked fine. I don't understand what is wrong with the code...can anyone help me?

**LOGCAT & DEBUG**

```
DalvikVM[localhost:8631]    
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
        DashboardActivity$MyLocationListener.onLocationChanged(Location) line: 75   
        LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(Message) line: 191 
        LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager$ListenerTransport, Message) line: 124  
        LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(Message) line: 140    
        LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99  
        Looper.loop() line: 123 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868  
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<6> Binder Thread #2] (Running) 
    Thread [<5> Binder Thread #1] (Running) 
    Thread [<7> MapService] (Running)   
    Thread [<8> TrafficService] (Running)   
    Daemon Thread [<10> RefQueueWorker@org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute@4610b970] (Running)
```

LINE 75 giving error.

Comment: Can you post your android-manifest.xml? I think you forgot to add the location permissions to it.

Comment: @Marcelo Just being curious, I also think permissions are the culprits. But according to the docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29), the method throws a `SecurityException` if "no suitable permission is present". Shouldn't this exception appear in logcat or even throw an ANR if it were run directly in the event thread?

Comment: I have written all these permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

Comment: @MisterSmith Yes, it should force close the application with a `SecurityException`, I missed the part that the application could get the location on the Emulator and the problem was on the real device only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're also requesting updates for the NETWORK_PROVIDER, you also need to include the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

My guess is that the line:

```
locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, currentLocListener);
```

...is throwing a SecurityException and therefore the following line that registers the GPS_PROVIDER is never executed.

To troubleshoot, I would recommend commenting out the line that requests updates from the NETWORK_PROVIDER, and then see if GPS works on a device.  Or, you can try including the above permission in your manifest, and then checking to make sure that the Locations you're receiving in the onLocationChanged() method are from the GPS_PROVIDER.

Also, try eliminating the first line where you're converting to String array. Instead, directly assign values to variables:

```
double lat = location.getLatitude();
double lng = location.getLongitude();
```

Comment: Thanks but still by commenting NETWORK PROVIDER it didnot help.

Comment: Try uncommenting that line and adding the coarse location permission to your manifest.  After doing this, if the network provider is working successfully you should see updates on the map.  If this works, then the issue is likely with the GPS hardware in your phone not being able to acquire a GPS fix.  When testing your and a Google Maps app on your device, did you test both back-to-back in the same physical location?  Buildings and other obstructions can prevent you from getting a GPS fix,  if you're in different locations.

Comment: basically my app crashes when I input gps lat and long from DDMS,
it gives error of null value at the line where lat and long are present.

Comment: Can you provide output log from DDMS?

Comment: Also, try eliminating the first line where you're converting to String array.  Instead, directly assign values to variables - double lat = location.getLatitude().